# CSS styling works on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

In this case, i'm using bootstrap and added my own class for custom styling. my custom style works on Chrome but not in Mozilla.. here is the example:

element:

```
<input class="form-control en-input-label" id="source" name="source" value="Personal Contact" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" readonly />
```

on Chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

but on Firefox, the style doesn't really apply, and it looks like this:

[image]

here is the css comparison from dev tools..

Chrome:

[image]

but, Firefox can't read the `en-input-label` class and go with the default class instead.

[image]

can anyone explain what happens? why chrome is able to read the `en-input-label` but Firefox can't ?

EDIT:

Here are css for `en-input-label`

```
.form-control.en-input-label, .form-control.en-input-label:read-only {
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

any other css related to the elems is `form-control` from bootstrap:

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
     transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

Comment: My only guess is that it's a caching issue. Try holding `SHIFT` while clicking the refresh icon (in both browsers). If that doesn't work, there's no other immediately-obvious reason why it should work in Chrome but not Firefox, and it's impossible to reproduce your problem without seeing your code. As such, can you please post the full CSS for `en-input-label` in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ObsidianAge i've updated my post. and no, it's not caching issue. i've tried that many times.

Comment: Can you put an example of this up online somewhere? We see lots of "it's not a caching issue" comments around here that get followed up by "turns out it was a caching issue". How have you determined it's not a caching issue? Have you accessed the URL to the CSS directly to confirm the rules are there?

Comment: @ceejayoz i'm trying to create it somewhere else. about caching, i tried to clear it from settings on each browser, i tried shfit+f5 everytime i made updates, i used versioning on my css everytime i update the source `<link rel="stylesheet" href="folder/css/custom.css?v=2122">`, i even tried to open on another devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that [Firefox needs a vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only), so:

`.form-control.en-input-label:-moz-read-only {`